# JavaScript find first RegExp match after certain index

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to find the first *RegExp* match after certain *index* in a *String* in JavaScript.

JavaScript `String.prototype.indexOf` offer a second parameter limit where the searching starts. But `indexOf` only supports `String`, not `RegExp`. `String.prototype.match` does use `RegExp`. But it does not support another parameter to start searching from certain index.

Thankfully, JavaScript provided `String.prototype.matchAll` to give all matches. (This could also be done with `RegExp.prototype.exec`.) Currently, I can do it like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} str
 * @param {RegExp} reg
 * @param {number} fromIndex
 */
function matchFrom(str, reg, fromIndex) {
  for (const match of str.matchAll(reg)) {
    if (match.index >= fromIndex) return match;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Above code works as what I expected. But it iterate from the very beginning. For a larger `str`. It could be slow (to my understanding, not tested). I'm wonder if there is a better way to achieve this.

---

- **Note**: String slicing may not help in a general case, since RegExp may contain lookbehind assertions. (Although the performance is also doubtful.)
- **Note** 2: Above code works only if I wrap the `reg` by `(?=(...))`, and adjust capture groups.

Comment: Every match of the string up until the found point must be iterated over regardless, for the general case, so if you're worried about the process being expensive, there isn't really any way around that - your code is the only good option I think

Comment: I would question why you need such a function. If you want performance restructure your solution to keep all the matches from matchAll run just once.

Comment: @gman What do you mean, keep all the matches? Are you talking about implementing a caching mechanism? (it'd help for repeated calls, I guess)

Comment: I mean change the code that's calling this function. The code above that is using this function should be refactored not to need this function. The fact that this function as very poor perf suggests the better solution is at a higher level

Comment: @gman Caching the matchAll results seems reasonable. I will have a try. (Although these methods may not be covered by this question.) Thank you.

Comment: @gman Caching makes code more complex than a simple non-regex solution in my use case. I would prefer to write for loop (state machine) now, if there isn't a better way. Anyway, thanks to your suggestions. But I will keep this question as is since it asking a general question and could be helpful to others imo.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739488/is-there-a-way-for-regexp-to-only-try-to-match-at-a-particular-index) and found an answer which I will share here.

```
function matchFrom(str, reg, fromIndex) {
    if (!reg.sticky) throw new Error("RegExp requires sticky (y) opyion.")
    reg.lastIndex = fromIndex
    return reg.exec(str)
}
```

Comment: Have not used sticky before. I will have a try with it. Maybe you can construct another reg by `new RegExp(reg.source, reg.flags.replace('y', '') + 'y')` without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: If you want to only match at fromIndex as I did then you would use the sticky option. If you want to match at any point greater than or equal to fromIndex then you would use global instead.

Answer (score 0):

Putting my comment into an answer...

Your solution seems correct and I don't know of a faster solution given the parameters of your quesiton

But, I think rather than answer the question directly I'd ask why do you need this function? We can't know without seeing your code but for example let say we have

```
for (let index = 0;; ++index) {
  const match = matchFrom(str, reg, index);
  if (!match) {
    break;
  }
  doSomethingWithMatch(match);
}
```

It seems to me it would be better to just re-write that

```
const matches = str.matchAll(reg);
for (const match in matches) {
  doSomethingWithMatch(match);
}
```

My point being the fact that `matchFrom` is slow suggests that maybe it's not a good function to have in the first place and that refactoring the code that's trying to use it is a better place to spend your efforts.